# Introduction of a validation step in a loop

Tags: python, validation

I created some code (it works fine) that does a loop of several actions on a webpage (using selenium). However, I would like to insert a validation point in the middle of the actions that if is not true, the loop should start the operations again (go to the next row).

So `if validation != "Select All (1)"` the loop must restart. Please note that I only know if the validation is true or not in the middle of the tasks because I make a search and basically if the search is successful i get the text `Select All (1)`, if it is not I get a different text.

My code is below (the original) and after that is my attempt to make said validation.
What happens now is that with my attempt to change the code, the code is working exactly the same. So I am not sure what's wrong.

Old code:

```
for row in rows:

    browser.get('https://wwww.test/')
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='agent_list_filter_id_2']").clear()
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='agent_list_filter_id_2']").send_keys(row)
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content-column']/div[4]/form/div[1]/span/span[1]").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='action-select-all']/span/span").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='action-delete']/span/span").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='btn_save']").click()
```

My attempt:

```
validation = ""
while validation != "Select All (1)":

   for row in rows:
        browser.get('https://wwww.test/')
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='agent_list_filter_id_2']").clear()
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='agent_list_filter_id_2']").send_keys(row)
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content-column']/div[4]/form/div[1]/span/span[1]").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        # here should be the validation, if not true, the loop should restart with other row (result not found)
        validation = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='action-select-all']/span/span").text
        # validatiom above this line
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='action-select-all']/span/span").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='action-delete']/span/span").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='btn_save']").click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add a [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue) after your validation line if it comes out `false`:

```
validation = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='action-select-all']/span/span").text
if validation != "Select All (1)":
    continue
```

This will `continue` to the next iteration of your `for` loop and skip the rest of the statements after it.

Comment: didnt work.. the validation  is different from Select All (1) and the loop didnt start again from the browser.get('https://wwww.test/') ...

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? What exactly would you like to happen?

Comment: if  browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='action-select-all']/span/span").text is not 'Select All (1)' the loop must restart.

Comment: my initial code with ´validation = ""
while validation != "Select All (1)":´must be kept right? thank you.

Comment: Yeah everything stays the same. The code I gave you is just in the middle of the `for` loop where you wanted the extra validation (even though I think you can change the `while` to `if`)

Comment: thank you. works perfect... but now i got a new challenge, because everytime the loop restarts because of the validation be false (starts from begining) a new step must be added, which is not needed if the validation is always true. How could I add that? the step is : `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content-column']/div[4]/form/div[1]/span/span[1]").click()`

Comment: anyway your answer is correct, this was not my initial question :/

Comment: Can you please open a new specific question for this? I will keep track and try to answer you there, no problem

Comment: ok, but will need to wait those 90minutes before ask again. thank you.

Comment: its here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559277/insert-a-new-action-only-if-the-loop-restart-because-of-the-while thank you!