# Insert a new action only if the loop restart because of the while

Tags: python

I would like to add a new line action only when the validation variable is not "Select All (1)").

For example: If the condition Validation is true "Select All (1)" I want the code to run normally, just lopping in the end and is doing that now. But when Validation is not "Select All (1)" I want to add a new command before the loop start (right now is starting from the beginning, but is not adding a specific action); the command missing is:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content-column']/div[4]/form/div[1]/spa‌​n/span[1]").click()
```

As explaining, this code above must be used only sometimes, when the loop is forced to restart.

This is the code missing:

```
validation = ""
while validation != "Select All (1)":

   for row in rows:
        browser.get('https://wwww.test')
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='agent_list_filter_id_2']").clear()
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='agent_list_filter_id_2']").send_keys(row)
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content-column']/div[4]/form/div[1]/span/span[1]").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        # validation starts here
        validation = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='action-select-all']/span/span").text
        if validation != "Select All (1)": # or anything that is a falsy validation
            continue
        # validation finish here
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='action-select-all']/span/span").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='action-delete']/span/span").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='btn_save']").click()
```

thank you for your inputs

Comment: Didn't understand the question at all. Please show an example if possible. Also, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you just want to add this line:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content-column']/div[4]/form/div[1]/spa‌​n/span[1]").click()
```

So why not just do this?

```
# validation starts here
validation = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='action-select-all']/span/span").text
if validation != "Select All (1)": # or anything that is a falsy validation
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content-column']/div[4]/form/div[1]/spa‌​n/span[1]").click()
    continue
# validation finish here
```

Then the command you wanted to end will execute before the loop restarts.

Let me know if that helped you out or if I misunderstood.

Comment: But this way this command will run always no matter the loop restart or not, right? This xpath is a search tab of the page, that will hide and unhide when I make a search, and then if the search doesn't find nothing it hides again the tab, that's why just in this situation I need to make it visible again . If always find the objects I just need to make it visible once in the beginning of program. Thanks!!

Comment: This command will run **only if** the loop restarts. That is what you wanted right?

Comment: hi, didnt work adding that line, it gets an error in that specific line

Comment: The line is something *you* wrote, I don't know if it should work or not... I just showed you where to insert it to get the flow like you wanted.. I don't understand the problem